# How to find the likelihood probability of an exponential data model

Tags: bayesian, inference, likelihood

I have a very basic knowledge in statistics, so I am struggling a bit with the ideas of Bayesian inference.

My data model looks like this,

$$ z(t) = \sum_{n = 1}^{N} e^{j 4\pi/\lambda \sqrt{(x_{n, t -1} + u_n.dt)^2 + (y_{n, t -1} + v_n.dt)^2}} + \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2) $$

Parameter space is $\theta = [u_n \quad v_n]$

The idea is to find a distribution for $u$ and $v$ given the measurements. I know the prior probability distributions for $u$ and $v$. So, that is $p(\theta) = p(u_n) . p(v_n)$. I assume they are independent. Am I correct here?

Then, as I understand from the model, $z$ is an exponential complex function of $u$ and $v$. Therefore, the probability density of $z$ shouldn't be the same as $u_n$ and $v_n$ right?

So, how to come up with the likelihood that is necessary in Bayesian inference algorithms? That is $p(z|\theta)$? Every example I see, they always start with a PDF model for the data instead of the data model directly. Any idea how to proceed?

In the equation, $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ is additive zero-mean Gaussian noise with variance $\sigma^2$, $dt$ is the time step. The $z$ samples are samples in time. The term $N$ is the number of targets. $x_n$ and $y_n$ are positions of $N$ targets and $u_n$ and $v_n$ are their velocities. I also see a potential difference between $z$ and $\theta$. The $\theta$ is a function of targets and $z$ is a signal in time $t$.

Comment: $z(t)$ according to your expression is gaussian with variance $\sigma^2$ and a mean defined by that sum , $z(t) \sim \mathcal N( \mu(t,\theta) , \sigma^2)$.  So the likelihood is $\log \mathcal L \sim  \sum (z(t) - \mu(t,\theta))^2 / \sigma^2 $

Comment: @J.Delaney If I am not wrong, the summation you wrote outside the parentheses is a summation over $t$ axis right?

Comment: right. If $z(t)$ is complex Just make sure you understand what is exactly the meaning of adding noise to it. I assume you have (independent?)  noise on both real and imaginary components, but it is not clear from your question

Comment: Ah yes! I didn't mention complex and independent noise. It is randomly generated from a Gaussian distribution (both real and imaginary parts).